# Whole-number powers

Tags: code-golf, math, number

Some numbers like `64` can be expressed as a whole-number power in multiple ways:

```
64 ^ 1
 8 ^ 2
 4 ^ 3
 2 ^ 6
```

Output a sorted array of all possible such powers (here, `[1,2,3,6]`) in as few bytes as possible.

---

## Input

A positive whole number that's greater than 1 and less than 10000.

---

## Output

An array of whole-number powers `p` (including `1`) for which the input can be expressed as `a^p` with whole-number `a`. The outputs may have decimals, as long as they are in order.

Any floating point issues must be handled by the program.

---

## Examples

```
Input: 3
Output: [1]

Input: 9
Output: [1, 2]

Input: 81
Output: [1, 2, 4]

Input: 729
Output: [1, 2, 3, 6]
```

---

## Scoreboard

For your score to appear on the board, it should be in this format:

```
# Language, Bytes
```

Strikethroughs shouldn't cause a problem.

```js
function getURL(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function getAnswers(){$.ajax({url:getURL(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),useData(answers)}})}function getOwnerName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function useData(e){var s=[];e.forEach(function(e){var a=e.body.replace(/<s>.*<\/s>/,"").replace(/<strike>.*<\/strike>/,"");console.log(a),VALID_HEAD.test(a)&&s.push({user:getOwnerName(e),language:a.match(VALID_HEAD)[1],score:+a.match(VALID_HEAD)[2],link:e.share_link})}),s.sort(function(e,s){var a=e.score,r=s.score;return a-r}),s.forEach(function(e,s){var a=$("#score-template").html();a=a.replace("{{RANK}}",s+1+"").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SCORE}}",e.score),a=$(a),$("#scores").append(a)})}var QUESTION_ID=58047,ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",answers=[],answer_ids,answers_hash,answer_page=1;getAnswers();var VALID_HEAD=/<h\d>([^\n,]*)[, ]*(\d+).*<\/h\d>/;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:10px 0 0 30px}#scores-cont{padding:10px;width:600px}#scores tr td:first-of-type{padding-left:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"><div id="scores-cont"><h2>Scores</h2><table class="score-table"><thead> <tr><td></td><td>User</td><td>Language</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="scores"></tbody></table></div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="score-template"><tr><td>{{RANK}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SCORE}}</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Yes! I overlooked it. Thank you very much. @steveverrill

Comment: My answer prints `[1 2 3 6]` for the last test case. Could it also print `[6 3 2 1]`, `[1.0 2.0 3.0 6.0]` or `[6.0 3.0 2.0 1.0]`?

Comment: The roots should be in ascending order; however, decimals are fine. @Dennis

Comment: What can we assume about input sizes and floating-point arithmetic? This affects the solution where you try to take roots of the number and see if the result is integer.

Comment: I've added some more details. Hopefully I've resolved these questions. @xnor

Comment: I think the references to roots were confusing everyone, so I rewrote it in terms of powers. Feel free to change things back.

Comment: I appreciate the edit! Suggestions and revisions are always welcome, provided they improve my question's quality (which I believe yours did). I've only recently started asking questions on this particular network, and find the community generally welcoming. Criticism and correction is much appreciated! @xnor

Comment: You've asked for a "program" but in most languages a program cannot output an array, only a text representation of one (to stdout or possibly as a return value). In Ruby, for example, this is normally the array elements separated by newlines, which looks different from your representation. Is this OK? Or do you require a function which returns an array?

Comment: Simply find the largest valid power and then list its factors!

Comment: If the language can not naturally return an array, as represented above, I will accept the closest alternative. @steveverrill

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/564/8478) [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/501/8478)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
f}Q^RTSQSQ
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%7DQ%5ERTSQSQ&input=64&debug=0)

For each power, it generates the list of all numbers up to the input taken to that power, and then checks if the input is in the list.

Answer (score 10):

### Haskell, 38

```haskell
f n=[b|b<-[1..n],n`elem`map(^b)[1..n]]
```

Pretty straightforward. The list comprehension finds values of `b` for which the input `n` appears among `[1^b, 2^b, ..., n^b]`. It suffices to check `b` in the range `[1..n]`.

Answer (score 9):

## Python 2, 53

```
lambda n:[i/n for i in range(n*n)if(i%n+1)**(i/n)==n]
```

Brute forces all combinations of bases in exponents in [0, n-1] and bases in [1, n].

Answer (score 8):

### Python 3, 56 bytes

```
lambda n:[i for i in range(1,n)if round(n**(1/i))**i==n]
```

This is really clumsy. Tests if each potential `i`-th root gives an integer by rounding it, taking it the power of `i`, and checking that it equals to original.

Directly checking that the root is a whole number is tricky because floating points give things like `64**(1/3) == 3.9999999999999996`. Rounding it to an integer let us check if taking the power returns to the original value. Thanks to ypercube for suggesting this, saving 1 byte.

feersum has a [shorter and more clever solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58064/20260). You all should really upvote that.

Comment: Wouldn't it be accurate if you checked `round(n**(1/i),0)**i==n` ?

Comment: @ypercube Good call, together with `0` being the default accuracy for round, this saves a byte.

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth, <strike>11</strike> <strike>10</strike> 12 bytes

```
fsmqQ^dTSQSQ
```

Checks all possible combinations of powers. Very slow.

Answer (score 5):

## APL, 17 bytes

```
(X=⌊X←N*÷⍳N)/⍳N←⎕
```

My first APL program; golfing suggestions are appreciated.

```
              N←⎕  ⍝ Store input into N
             ⍳     ⍝ The list [1 2 ... N]
            /      ⍝ Select the elements A for which
      N*÷⍳N)       ⍝ N^(1/A)
(X=⌊X←             ⍝ equals its floor (that is, is an integer)
```

Comment: Please add pseudocode/explanation. But +1 (can't vote right now) for using APL ( - *being terse before it was cool*) :-)

Comment: Also +1, much love for APL. Ultimate golfing vehicle.

Comment: Based on the pseudocode, this is unlikely to work (unless APL performs an approximate floating-point equality test). For example, with `pow(pow(7,3),1./3))` I get `6.99999999999999` in C or Python. This is because accuracy is lost when calculating 1/A.

Comment: @feersum I don't know about offline interpreters, but all powers of 3 work correctly on tryapl.org.

Comment: @ThomasKwa It seems that an approximate equality test is indeed used. http://www.dyalog.com/uploads/documents/Papers/tolerant_comparison/tolerant_comparison.htm

Answer (score 5):

## CJam, 23 bytes

```
rimF{1=:E){E\d%!},}%:&p
```

This works by taking the prime factorization of **n** and computing the intersection of the divisors of all exponents.

It is a bit longer than [my other solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58049), but I expect it to work (and finish instantly) for all integers between **2** and **2<sup>63</sup> - 1**.

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=rimF%7B1%3D%3AE)%7BE%5Cd%25!%7D%2C%7D%25%3A%26p&input=4052555153018976267).

#### How it works

```
ri                       Read an integer from STDIN.
  mF                     Push its prime factorization.
    {             }%     For each [prime exponent]:
     1=:E                  Retrieve the exponent and save it in E.
         ){     },         Filter; for each I in [0 ... E]:
           E\d%              Compute E % Double(I).
                             (Casting to Double is required to divide by 0.)
               !             Push the logical NOT of the modulus.
                           Keep I if the result is truhty, i.e., if I divides E.
                    :&   Intersect all resulting arrays of integers.
                      p  Print the resulting array.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ÆEg/ÆD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm2u6/uE2l/@H2x81rfn/P9pYx1LHwlDH3MhSx8xEx8jAQMfEwCAWAA)

```
    ÆD    The list of divisors of
ÆE        the exponents in the prime factorization of the input
   /      reduced by
  g       greatest common divisor.
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES5), <s>73 bytes</s> <s>81 bytes</s> <s>79 bytes</s> 75 bytes

```
for(n=+prompt(),p=Math.pow,i=0;i++<n;)p(.5+p(n,1/i)|0,i)==n&&console.log(i)
```

Checks to see if closest integer power of possible root equals `n`. `~~(.5+...)` is equivalent to `Math.round(...)` for expressions within integer range (0 to 2^31 - 1).

**Edit:** Used lazy `&&` logic instead of `if` to shave 2 bytes and added prompt for input since question added a clarification. Was previously assuming input was stored in `n`.

**Edit 2:** Changed `~~(.5+...)` to `.5+...|0` to save two bytes by avoiding grouping.

**Edit 3:** Removed `var`  to save 4 bytes. In non-strict mode, this is acceptable.

Comment: You can shave a couple bytes by juggling expressions: for(var p=Math.pow,i=1;i++<n;p(~~(.5+p(n,1/i)),i)==n&&console.log(i));

Comment: @Alhadis thanks for your input, I'll make an edit in a bit

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You could squeeze `p=Math.pow` into prompt saving 1 byte

Comment: @vihan, that would be an invalid declaration, since `var` is required

Comment: Unless you meant `for` instead of `prompt`..

Comment: Erm. Technically, `prompt` isn't JavaScript... it's a method defined by the DOM's Window interface, which is mean to be language-agnostic. But yeah. ;)

Comment: @Alhadis it's valid client-side JavaScript, and the only method of input available that doesn't require using the DOM, plus prompt is commonly accepted in code-golfing on this site so I already know it's allowed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
≥^↙.?≥ℕ≜
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmpofbFjzc1Vn7cOuE/486l8Y9apupZw9kPGqZ@qhzzv//0cY6ljoWhjrmRpY6ZiY6RgYGOiYGBrEA)

Takes input through its input variable and [generates](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10753/85334) each power through its output variable, in ascending order as required, unlike the old solution `≥ℕ≜^↙.?∧` which just so happens to have the exact same length.

```
≥           Some number which is less than or equal to
            the input,
 ^          when raised to the power of
  ↙.        the output,
    ?       is the input.
       ≜    Label
            the output
      ℕ     as a whole number
     ≥      which is less than or equal to
    ?       the input.
```

I don't have any rigorous justification for asserting that every exponent is no greater than the input, but in order for the program to actually terminate it needs to be bounded.

`ḋḅlᵛf` is a far shorter (non-generator) solution for all of the given test cases, but it fails if the input isn't a power of a product of distinct primes. (Come to think of it, since all of the test cases are powers of primes, `ḋlf` also works...) The best I've come up with to salvage the idea, `ḋḅlᵐḋˢ⊇ᵛ×f`, comes out to 10 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
Ó¿Ñ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8ORD@w9P/P/fxMzM1AwA)

Port of [Unrelated String’s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187061/6484).

```
Ó       # exponents in the prime factorization
 ¿      # gcd
  Ñ     # divisors
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 20 bytes

```
ri_,1df+\1$fmL9fmO&p
```

For input **n**, this computes **log<sub>b</sub> n** for all **b** less or equal to **n** and keeps the results that are integers.

This should work for all integers between **2** and **9,999**. Run time is roughly **O(n)**.

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri_%2C1df%2B%5C1%24fmL9fmO%26p&input=4913).

#### How it works

```
ri                   e# Read an integer N from STDIN.
  _,                 e# Copy N and transform it into [0 ... N-1].
    1df+             e# Add 1.0 to each, resulting in [1.0 ... Nd].
        \1$          e# Swap the array with N and copy the array.
           fmL       e# Mapped log base N: N [1.0 ... Nd] -> [log1(N) ... logN(N)]
              9fmO   e# Round each logarithm to 9 decimals.
                  &  e# Intersect this array with [1.0 ... Nd].
                   p e# Print the result.
```

Comment: Is 15,625 the only input on which it fails or is it the only which failed that you tested?

Comment: There are most definitely others. In fact, I just found out that it failed for **4913** as well, which made my previous revision invalid.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES7, 66 bytes

Takes advantage of experimental array comprehensions. Only works on Firefox.

```
n=>[for(i of Array(n).keys(m=Math.pow))if(m(0|.5+m(n,1/i),i)==n)i]
```

Possible golfing. I'll probably try to squish the expressions a little shorter and hopefully find an alternative to the long `Array(n).keys()` syntax.

Could be shorter but JavaScript has horribly floating point accuracy.

Comment: Ah, learned something new... cool.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 50

```
->n{(1..n).map{|i|(n**(1.0/i)+1e-9)%1>1e-8||p(i)}}
```

Prints to screen.

## Ruby, 57

```
->n{a=[]
(1..n).map{|i|(n**(1.0/i)+1e-9)%1>1e-8||a<<i}
a}
```

Returns an array.

In test program:

```
f=->n{(1..n).map{|i|(n**(1.0/i)+1e-9)%1>1e-8||puts(i)}}

g=->n{a=[]
(1..n).map{|i|(n**(1.0/i)+1e-9)%1>1e-8||a<<i}
a}

f.call(4096)
puts g.call(4096)
```

Calculates each root and tests them modulo 1 to see if the remainder is less than 1e-8. Due to limited precision some valid integer roots are calculated to be the form 0.9999.., hence the need to add 1e-9 to them.

Up to the nth root of n is calculated, which is total overkill, but seemed the shortest way to write a non-infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
£ÅeÉåC
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9c8f65908643&i=3%0A9%0A81%0A729&a=1&m=2)

All divisors of the gcd of exponents in the prime factorization.  It's the same as the jelly algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

## **DC, 104 bytes**

Input is taken from terminal, output is printed and also on the stack.

Because this uses the ? operator, you need to use `dc -e "<solution>"` or `dc <file with solution in it>`.

Nobody ever sees my answers, let alone vote on them, but I really just enjoy solving problems in DC. It's the least efficient solution in this thread so far, but I thought I'd post it anyways.

```
1sb?sn[lesi]ss[lble1+dse^dln=sln>c]sc[liSflq1+sq]sm[Lfplq1-dsq0<p]dsp[lb1+sb0si0selcxli0!=mlbln!=h]dshxx
```

starter stuff

```
1sb           Store 1 in register b
?sn           Store user input in register n
[lesi]ss      A macro to copy the e to the i register, stored in the s register
```

Macro to raise a base to all powers until the result is larger than the target or equal to the target

```
[lble1+dse^dln=sln>c]sc
[lb                 ]   load our base num (register b)
[  le               ]   load our exponent (register e)
[    1+dse          ]   add 1 to the exponent, copy and store in the e register
[         ^d        ]   raise the base to the exponent and copy it
[           ln=s    ]   load the user input, if that is equal to the power result run the macro in register s
[               ln>c]   load the user input, if it's greater than the power result run the macro in register c (this one)
[                   ]sc save this macro in register c
```

Macro to save a valid exponent value as found from the above exponent macros to another stack

```
[liSflq1+sq]sm
[liSf      ]     copy the i register to the top of the stack in register f
[    lq1+sq]     add 1 to the q register
[          ]sm   save this macro in the m register
```

Macro to run the 2x above macro (macro c) through all bases from 2 to our target number

```
[lb1+sb0si0selcxli0!=mlbln!=h]dsh
[lb1+sb                      ]     add 1 to the base number
[      0si0se                ]     reset the i and e registers (previously found value and exponent
[            lcx             ]     load and run the c macro
[               li0!=m       ]     load the result of the c macro and if it's not 0, run m to save it to the f stack
[                     lbln!=h]     if our base number is not equal to our target number, run macro h (this macro)
[                            ]dsh  duplicate this macro and save one copy, so that one is left on the stack to run later
```

Macro to print the values from the f stack

```
[Lfplq1-dsq0<p]dsp
[Lfp          ]      load the top value from the f register and print it
[   lq1-dsq   ]      load the q register and subtract one from it and save it
[          0<p]      if the q register is greater than 0, run macro p (this macro) again
[             ]dsp   duplicate this macro and save one copy, so that one is left on the stack to run later

xx finally run the two macros on the stack (h and then p)
```

Comment: I would guess that not many people know DC. Answering new questions (especially being one of the earliest answers) will help with getting more attention. You might also try using TIO links for your answers, as that's very popular. Here's [DC on TIO](https://tio.run/#dc).

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely use that for answers going forwards!

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 46 bytes

Brute force solution. Self-explanatory; for input \$n\$, find all numbers \$e\$ where for some \$b\$, \$b^e=n\$.

```ruby
->n{(0..n).select{|e|(1..n).find{|b|b**e==n}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNATy9PU684NSc1uaS6JrVGwxAskJaZl1Jdk1STpKWVamubV1tb@79AIS06PbWkWK8kPz4z9r@ZCQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 93 bytes

```cs
g=n=>Enumerable.Range(1,n);
f=n=>g(n).SelectMany(x=>g(n).Where(y=>(Math.Pow(x,y)==n))).Reverse()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hczNCoJAFAXgvU8hru7ANGBFP9jMrqBICFu4NrnqgF1hZix9erMI2uXynPNxcjvLrR4OLeU7TY4f99Te0WS3Gt9ZKb@IvD9r6cuBpPr1IsmoRAg5saiQ41QCMXHFGnMXZ9RD963SCg1CLxXEmavEpXlCx3smJTHGRIIPNBaBDZGXGu3wrAnBOqOpFKdGEwQ84H4Bq@XIJ8ximmynySacNuv552h4AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 bytes

```
õ
f@mpX øN
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9QpmQG1wWCD4Tg&input=NjQ)

```
õ            :Implicit input of integer U
õ            :Range [1,U]
f@mpX øN     :Reassign to U
f            :Filter
 @           :By passing each X through the following function
  m          :  Map U
   pX        :    Raise to the power of X
      ø      :  Contains
       N     :    Any element of the (singelton) array of inputs
```