# Find the n-th perfect power!

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, number-theory

A perfect power is a number of the form \$a^b\$, where \$a>0\$ and \$b>1\$.

For example, \$125\$ is a perfect power because it can be expressed as \$5^3\$.

## Goal

Your task is to write  a program/function that finds the \$n\$-th perfect power, given a positive integer \$n\$.

## Specs

- The first perfect power is \$1\$ (which is \$1^2\$).
- Input/output in any reasonable format.
- Built-ins are **allowed**.

## Further information

- [OEIS A001597](http://oeis.org/A001597)

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest solution in bytes wins.

## Testcases

```
input  output
1      1
2      4
3      8
4      9
5      16
6      25
7      27
8      32
9      36
10     49
```

Comment: Uptil what number should this work? Infinity?

Comment: A reasonable amount.

Comment: What about a language that uses only a data type of one bit?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code I think a language like that is considered in the loopholes.

Comment: not loophole but rule-escapist

Comment: @Agawa001 Yes it is a [standard loophole](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8245/24877) which are no longer funny.

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/58047/8478) [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/501/8478) [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/564/8478)

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica, 34 bytes

```
(Union@@Array[#^#2#&,{#,#}])[[#]]&
```

Generates an \$n\times n\$ array \$A_{ij} = i^{1+j}\$, flattens it, and returns the \$n\$th element.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
µÆE;¬g/’µ#Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wrXDhkU7wqxnL-KAmcK1I-G5qg&input=MTA).

#### Background

Every positive integer \$k\$ can be factorized uniquely as the product of powers of the first \$m\$ primes, i.e., \$k=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_m^{\alpha_m}\$, where \$\alpha_m>0\$.

We have that \$a^b\$ (\$b>1\$) for some positive integer \$a\$ if and only if \$b\$ is a divisor of all exponents \$\alpha_j\$.

Thus, an integer \$k > 1\$ is a perfect power if and only if \$\gcd(α_1, ⋯, α_m) ≠ 1\$.

#### How it works

```
µÆE;¬g/’µ#Ṫ  Main link. No arguments.

µ            Make the chain monadic, setting the left argument to 0.
        µ#   Find the first n integers k, greater or equal to 0, for which the
             preceding chain returns a truthy value.
             In the absence of CLAs, n is read implicitly from STDIN.
 ÆE          Compute the exponents of the prime factorization of k.
   ;¬        Append the logical NOT of k, i.e., 0 if k > 0 and 1 otherwise.
             This maps 1 -> [0] and [0] -> [1].
     g/      Reduce the list of exponents by GCD.
             In particular, we achieved that 1 -> 0 and 0 -> 1.
       ’     Decrement; subtract 1 from the GCD.
             This maps 1 to 0 (falsy) and all other integers to a truthy value.
          Ṫ  Tail; extract the last k.
```

Comment: I haven't seen STDIN at all. I have no idea how to use it at all.

Comment: Nice use of the definition of perfect power having to do with prime factorization. Could you include this algorithm in the description?

Comment: @KennyLau Done.

Comment: I don't understand how 21^2 includes the first or third prime in its factorization. Could you please help me understand what you mean by "Every positive integer k can be factorized uniquely as the product of powers of the first m primes...where [the exponent] `a_n > 0`?" It seems to me in the factorization for 21^2 the exponents for p = 2 and p = 5 are zero.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Sorry, that should have been **a_m > 0**. The previous **m-1** exponents may include zeroes.

Comment: ......cool, tx!

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

Code:

```
LD>m€`{Ú`¹<@
```

Uses **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=TEQ-beKCrGB7w5pgwrk8QA&input=MTA).

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, <s>57</s> <s>31</s> 30 bytes

```
@(n)unique((1:n)'.^(2:n+1))(n)
```

I just noticed again that Octave does not need `ndgrid` (while Matlab does)=)

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, 16 bytes

```
ri_),_2f+ff#:|$=
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri_)%2C_2f%2Bff%23%3A%7C%24%3D&input=8)

#### Explanation

This uses a similar idea to LegionMammal's Mathematica answer.

```
ri    e# Read input and convert to integer N.
_),   e# Duplicate, increment and turn into range [0 1 ... N].
_2f+  e# Duplicate and add two to each element to get [2 3 ... N+2].
ff#   e# Compute the outer product between both lists over exponentiation.
      e# This gives a bunch of perfect powers a^b for a ≥ 0, b > 1.
:|    e# Fold set union over the list, getting all unique powers generated this way.
$     e# Sort them.
=     e# Retrieve the N+1'th power (because input is 1-based, but CJam's array access
      e# is 0-based, which is why we included 0 in the list of perfect powers.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
*þḊFQṢị@o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9qZWxsef//KsO@4biKRlHhuaLhu4tAb/8xMDvDhyTigqxH/w)

As far as I can tell, only the `þ` quick didn't exist when the challenge was posted, but [this](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/g4Y4uLf1HTWsCH@5c9HB3t0P@f0MD68PtKkAh9/8A) 10 byter would've worked back then as well as now.

### How it works

```
*þḊFQṢị@o - Main link. Takes n on the left
  Ḋ       - Yield [2, 3, ..., n]
 þ        - Create an n×(n-1) matrix then
            for each entry (i,j) (i = 1,2,...,n and j = 2,3,...n),
            fill it with the following:
*         -   i*j
   F      - Flatten the matrix
    Q     - Remove duplicates
     Ṣ    - Sort
            For all n > 1, this yields an ordered list of perfect powers below n*n
            For n = 1, this yields an empty list
      ị@  - Take the nth item in this list. n = 1 yields 0
        o - Replace 0 with n, to handle n = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Sage (version 6.4, probably also others): <s>64</s> 63

```
lambda n:[k for k in range(1+n^2)if(0+k).is_perfect_power()][n]
```

Creates a lambda function that returns `n`th perfect power. We rely on the fact that it is found within the first `n^2` integers. (The `1+n^2` is necessary for `n=1,2`. The `0+k` bit is necessary to convert `int(k)` to `Integer(k)`.)

Byte off for `xrange`->`range`, thanks Dennis.

Just a fun fact: `0` is a perfect power by Sage's standards, fortunately, because then `1` is the 1st element of the list, not 0th :)

Comment: So this is Python except for the prime power part?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy And `is_perfect_power()`

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - <s>12</s> 11 bytes

Obvious approach, just goes through and checks all numbers.

```
e.ffsI@ZTr2
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e.ffsI%40ZTr2&input=4&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10&debug=0).

Answer (score 1):

## J, 29 bytes

Based on the @LegionMammal978's [method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78985/find-the-n-th-perfect-power/78992#78992).

```
<:{[:/:~@~.[:,/[:(^/>:)~>:@i.
```

### Usage

```
   f =: <:{[:/:~@~.[:,/[:(^/>:)~>:@i.
   f " 0 (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
1 4 8 9 16 25 27 32 36 49
```

### Explanation

```
<:{[:/:~@~.[:,/[:(^/>:)~>:@i.
                           i.  Create range from 0 to n-1
                        >:     Increments each in that range, now is 1 to n
               [:              Cap, Ignores input n
                    >:         New range, increment from previous range to be 2 to n+1 now
                  ^/           Forms table using exponentation between 1..n and 2..n+1
             ,/                Flattens table to a list
         ~.                    Takes only distinct items
     /:~                       Sorts the list
<:                             Decrements the input n (since list is zero-based index)
  {                            Selects value from resulting list at index n-1
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, 9 bytes

```
:tQ!^uSG)
```

[Try it online](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OnRRIV51U0cp&input=Nw)

This is a port of Flawr's Octave solution to MATL, make the matrix of powers up to `n^(n+1)`, and get the `n`-th one.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, <s>64</s> 32 bytes

```
n->sort(∪([1:n]'.^[2:n+1]))[n]
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts an integer and returns an integer. To call it, assign it to a variable.

The idea here is the same as in LegionMammal's Mathematica [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78992/20469): We take the outer product of the integers 1 to *n* with 2 to *n* + 1, collapse the resulting matrix column-wise, take unique elements, sort, and get the *n*<sup>th</sup> element.

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=Zj1uLT5zb3J0KOKIqihbMTpuXScuXlsyOm4rMV0pKVtuXQoKZm9yIGkgPSAxOjEwCiAgICBwcmludGxuKGksICI6ICIsIGYoaSkpCmVuZA&input=) (includes all test cases)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 87

```js
n=>(b=>{for(l=[i=0,1];b<n*n;++b)for(v=b;v<n*n;)l[v*=b]=v;l.some(x=>n==i++?v=x:0)})(2)|v
```

*Less golfed*

```js
f=n=>{
  for(b=2, l=[0,1]; b < n*n; ++b)
    for(v = b; v < n*n;)
      l[v*=b] = v;
  i = 0;
  l.some(x => n == i++ ? v=x : 0);
  return v;
  // shorter alternative, but too much memory used even for small inputs
  // return l.filter(x=>x) [n-1];
}
```

**Test**

```js
f=n=>(b=>{for(l=[i=0,1];b<n*n;++b)for(v=b;v<n*n;)l[v*=b]=v;l.some(x=>n==i++?v=x:0)})(2)|v

function test(){
  var v=+I.value
  O.textContent=f(v)
}
  
test()
```

```html
<input type=number id=I value=10><button onclick='test()'>-></button>
<span id=O></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Actually, 18 bytes

```
;;u@ⁿr;`;√≈²=`M@░E
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=Ozt1QOKBv3I7YDviiJriiYjCsj1gTUDilpFF&input=MTA) (may not work due to needing an update)

Explanation:

```
;;u@ⁿr;`;√≈²=`M@░E
;;u@ⁿr              push range(n**(n+1))
      ;`;√≈²=`M@░   filter: take if
        ;√≈²=         int(sqrt(x))**2 == x
                 E  get nth element
```

Answer (score 1):

## ><>, 108 bytes

```
:1)?v  >n;
$:@@\&31+2>2$:@@:@
:1=?\@$:@*@@1-
:~$~<.1b+1v!?(}:{:~~v?(}:{:v?=}:{
1-:&1=?v~~>~61.     >~1+b1.>&
```

This program requires the input number to be present on the stack before running.

It took quite a lot to reduce the number of wasted bytes down to 7!

After a check to see if the input is `1`, the program checks each number, `n`, from 4 in turn to see if it's a perfect power. It does this by starting with `a=b=2`. If `a^b == n`, we've found a perfect power, so decrement the number of perfect powers left to find - if we've already found the right number, output.

If `a^b < n`, `b` is incremented. If `a^b > n`, `a` is incremented. Then, if `a == n`, we've found that `n` isn't a perfect power, so increment `n`, resetting `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
!¹OuṠ×^tḣ→
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9odXNr//8hwrlPdeG5oMOXXnThuKPihpL///8y)

### Explanation

```
!¹OuṠ×^tḣ→ Range 1..n+1 (ḣ called with 1 given an empty list)
    Ṡ      hookf: Ṡ f g x = f (g x) x
     ×^     f: apply power to all possible pairs from two lists
       t    g: tail (1..n → 2..n)
   u       all unique powers
  O        sort in ascending order
!¹         element at index n
```

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
!¹uO§×^…2ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9odXNr//8hwrl1T8Knw5de4oCmMuG4o////zE)

Dominic Van Essen's solution.

### Explanation

```
!¹uO§×^…2ḣ
    §      fork: § f g h x = f (g x) (h x)
     ×^     f: apply power to all possible pairs from two lists
       …2   g: inclusive range from 2..n (works for n<2)
         ḣ  h: range from 1..n
   O        sort in ascending order
  u         all unique powers
!¹         element at index n
```

Comment: I got ```!¹uO§×^…2ḣ``` which is also 10 bytes.  You'll get the upvote when you post your explanation...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen haha.. nice.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen added yours as well.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 44 bytes

```r
n=scan();unique(sort(outer(1:n,2:n,`^`)))[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8@2ODkxT0PTujQvs7A0VaM4v6hEI7@0JLVIw9AqT8cIiBPiEjQ1NaPzYv8bGvwHAA)

Same approach as the [Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78992/95126).

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES7), 104 bytes

```
n=>(a=[...Array(n)]).map(_=>a.every(_=>(p=i**++j)>n*n?0:r[p]=p,i+=j=1),r=[i=1])&&r.sort((a,b)=>a-b)[n-1]
```

Works by computing all powers not greater than n², sorting the resulting list and taking the nth element.

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 126

```
r->{int n,i,k;if(r==1)return r;for(n=i=2,r--;;){for(k=i*i;k<=n;k*=i)if(k==n){i=--r>0?++n:n;if(r<1)return n;}if(--i<2)i=++n;}}
```

Comment: Would it be shorter to use recursion?

Comment: Good, idea, needs a lot of planning though.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 82 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=0:n and f(n-any(a**b==i for a in range(i)for b in range(i)),i+1)or~-i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcyxCoMwFIXhvU9xxlwboaHgIORhbrBpL9QTCS4uffWoU13/D/5lWz@Fz9Zy/OqcJgW9xcdIKCdkx165Oe26FKMhlwqFEVX5fjmTM6RrEG/3IKX@emsn8o/Bh0HGG7BU4@qOt0jbAQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
µNDÓ2šθ2@
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0FY/l8OTjY4uPLfDyOH/f1MA) or [verify a few more test cases](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9vc2FiaWX/MjVFTj8iIOKGkiAiP07/wrVORMOTMsWhzrgyQP99LC7Ctf8).

**Explanation:**

```python
µ         # Loop until the counter_variable (0 by default) equals the (implicit) input:
 ND       #  Push the current 0-based loop-index `N` twice
   Ó      #  Pop one, and push all its exponents of prime factorization [a,b,c,d,...] in
          #  [2^a,3^b,5^c,7^d,...]
          #  (for N=0 and N=1, this will results in an empty list)
    2š    #  Prepend a 2 (for the edge cases N=0 and N=1)
      θ   #  Pop the list, and leave just the last value
       2@ #  Check if this is larger than or equal to 2
          #  (if it is: implicitly increase the counter_variable by 1)
          # (after the loop, implicitly output the last `N` that's still on the stack)
```

Minor note: the `@` in my answer using the latest 05AB1E version is a builtin for `>=`, whereas the `@` used in [*@Adnan*'s existing 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79043/52210) using the legacy 05AB1E version is a builtin to push the \$n^{th}\$ item on the stack.